# If $\gcd(|A|,|B|)=1$, $|AB| = |A||B|$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $A,B$ are subgroups of a finite group $G$. Prove that if $\gcd(|A|,|B|)=1$, then $|AB|=|A||B|$.

Suppose that $G$ has order $n$. Let $A$ have order $a$ and $B$ have order $b$, where $a|n$ and $b|n$ since $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of $G$.

$A \cap B$ is a subgroup of $G$, so $|A\cap B|$ also divides $n$. But $A \cap B$ is also a subgroup of both $A$ and $B$, so $|A\cap B|$ also divides both $a$ and $b$.

But $\gcd(|A|,|B|)=1$, so $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, so $|A\cap B|$ must be 1.

So $A \cap B = \{e_G\}$, since $a^1=a$ only when $a=e$.

So $|AB|=\frac{|A||B|}{|\{e\}|}=\frac{|A||B|}{1}=|A||B|$.

I'm not sure if I'm oversimplifying the question. I feel like I'm not, but this proof was also pretty straight forward since the two theorems I used here were right next to each other in the book we're using, so I thought it might be better to check to make sure I haven't missed anything. Thank you in advance for any advice you could offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually overcomplicated the issue. The key point is indeed to realise that $|A \cap B|$ is a common divisor of $|A|$ and $|B|$ (since $A\cap B$ is a subgroup of both $A$ and $B$ and Lagrange's theorem) and the assumption with the gcd then forces $|A \cap B|=1$, so that the result follows from the formula $$|AB|=\frac{|A||B|}{|A \cap B|}$$

Note that you don't need that $G$ is a finite group, just that $A$ and $B$ are finite subgroups with the given condition.